# Source model "mobilegifting / attributes_distribution" for the attribute "distributionsweg" was not found | Magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, source-model

I am facing `"source model "xxx / xxx_xxx" for the attribute "xxx" was not found"` with many module who's module name(Retailo_MobileGifting) is canonical.

To change the name of all module is not a good idea.
How can I solve it.